# Date to string conversion showing incorrect format in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

My HTML has:

```
<input type="date" name="dto" id="chosendate">
```

My JS is:

```
var x = document.getElementById("chosendate").value;
var formatteddate = x.toString();
```

The user inputs the date in dd/mm/yyyy.
Though this conversion then shows it as yyyy/mm/dd.

I have tried toLocaleDateString but it still doesnt work. 
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: probably x is a string, and needs to be converted to Date first: `var formatteddate = (new Date(x).toLocaleDateString()`

Comment: I tried it and it outputs as invalid date

Answer (score 1):

As it is string dumb solution can be:

```
const formatteddate =  x.split`-`.reverse().join`-`;
```